# How to migrate existing geoserver standalone app to web archive?

Tags: tomcat, gis, war, geoserver

I am using Geoserver 2.10.1 and I already developed GIS application using standalone version. Now how do I convert existing geoserver standalone app to web archive so that I copy that web archive to tomcat server which is running other web applications under development which will access the services provided by geoserver web archive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to locate and backup your data directory. Look under the settings menu if you don't know where it is. It's all pretty well covered in the [documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/index.html).

1. Stop existing GeoServer
2. add geoserver.war to tomcat
3. edit `WEB-INF/web.xml` [look for set the param-value](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html#context-parameter) to point to the old data directory

   ...
       
         GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR
         /var/lib/geoserver_data
       
       ...
4. Or set a `GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR` [environmental variable](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html#windows).
5. Or set a [container property](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/datadirectory/setting.html#java-system-property)

Comment: I copied geoserver from webapp directory of geoserver to my tomcat sever webapps directory and set the environment variable for GEOSERVER_DATA_DIR and that worked but still facing some issues like

Comment: log4j:WARN File option not set for appender [geoserverlogfile].
log4j:WARN Are you using FileAppender instead of ConsoleAppender?     and when i pan and zoom on maps I get exceptions being related to PNG tile encoding.

Comment: ignore the warnings. for the PNG issues I'd ask a new question (after marking this one accepted)